# Difference between MSP430 binary files in Debug and Release folders in Code Composer Studio

Tags: binaryfiles, msp430, code-composer

I am currently using CCS Version: 4.2.5.00005.  I am developing with the MSP430F5437A.

I have found that whenever I build the project I am working on that under both the projects Debug and Release folder I find a .txt hex file.  I have used the file under the Release folder for programming the target hardware via the Bootstrap Loader so I know that that file works well enough.

However, I was researching about programming the MSP430 via a 3rd party tool (such as provided by Elprotronic) and found of a property I can select under C/C++ Build -> Build Steps -> Apply Predefined Step that builds and places a TI-TXT file in the Debug folder.  It appears to me that this file should be the same as the one that I have used in the Release folder.  However, the two files are different in size with the one in the Release folder being larger (the opposite of what I would expect).

So my question is, what is the difference between these two text files? They appear to both be binary files that can be used to program a device, but why then would they be different?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have answered my own question:
I looked through all the possible differences between the release and debug properties and actually found that the debug version was using an older compiler version.  I've now made sure that both use the same compiler version and the .txt files now appear to be the same.

Comment: How could the hex file in the debug version have been compiled with an older compiler version?

Answer (score 0):

The Debug and Release files should be different. That's why the compiler gives you the option of having 2 builds.  The Release file could be larger or smaller, depending on the optimization priorities (speed vs size).